# Html file input field add files? (instead of replace)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a Html file input field which can add multiple files to the form, instead of replacing existing chosen files.

This is the basic file input element for uploading multiple files:

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload" multiple>
```

But it replaces previously chosen files :(

I can't believe that html doesn't have a built-in functionality for adding multiple files, but all solutions i have seen so far involve adding some external library which is not ideal.

Comment: HTML is a document markup language to create a structure, an outline, for that document. It is not a programming language and that is why it will never allow for adding files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is question for SO.

The file field, multiple or not, will always replace the previous selection. What you have to do is store the selection somewhere else each time user selects a file.

The file field has a property `files`, which contains a `FileList` object, which is basically a list of `File` objects, each one with some properties like `name`, `type` and `size`.

If you listen to the `change` event, you could just add the files just selected to your own variable and even present them to the user and allow him to remove a file. You could immediately start uploading the files via AJAX or submit all files when the form is submitted.

See:

https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742956/file-field-append-file-list

Answer (score 1):

I have never had the problem of overwriting previously uploaded files.  On the backend your code will save the files.  A simple way to do this is use a counter from a database so that you save the file with a unique ID.